# Delete everything after the nth mention of a character in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, text-files

I have a tab delimited text file:

```
ASSI-3_2    scaf0270669_20068.102_wgs
ASSI-4_3    scaf0189112_70083.538_rad
ASSI-5_4    scaf0083789_70072.963_wgs
ASSI-8_7    scaf0423760_50193.589_dart
ASSI-11_10  scaf0285971_60192.428_wgs
ASSI-12_11  scaf0409557_70062.641_wgs
ASSI-13_12  scaf0430981
```

I want to get rid of everything after the 3rd '_' character:

```
ASSI-3_2    scaf0270669_20068.102
ASSI-4_3    scaf0189112_70083.538
ASSI-5_4    scaf0083789_70072.963
ASSI-8_7    scaf0423760_50193.589
ASSI-11_10  scaf0285971_60192.428
ASSI-12_11  scaf0409557_70062.641
ASSI-13_12  scaf0430981
```

The way that I do it is to replace the third underscore with a @ and then delete everything after the @:

```
sed -r 's/_/@/3' | sed -r 's/@.*//'
```

Is there a command in bash that I can use that will allow me to do this in one go?

I tried this with no luck:

```
sed -r 's/_.*//3'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cut` you can do this:

```
cut -d_ -f1-3 file

ASSI-3_2    scaf0270669_20068.102
ASSI-4_3    scaf0189112_70083.538
ASSI-5_4    scaf0083789_70072.963
ASSI-8_7    scaf0423760_50193.589
ASSI-11_10  scaf0285971_60192.428
ASSI-12_11  scaf0409557_70062.641
ASSI-13_12  scaf0430981
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -F_ 'NF>3{$0=$1 FS $2 FS $3} 1' file

ASSI-3_2    scaf0270669_20068.102
ASSI-4_3    scaf0189112_70083.538
ASSI-5_4    scaf0083789_70072.963
ASSI-8_7    scaf0423760_50193.589
ASSI-11_10  scaf0285971_60192.428
ASSI-12_11  scaf0409557_70062.641
ASSI-13_12  scaf0430981
```

Comment: While your awk solution will work with the sample input in the question, it doesn't work if there happen to be additional underscores on the line. You'd probably want to use a simple for loop instead. If its condition only gets evaluated once, it's equivalent to an `if`, but has the flexibility to handle more complex input.

Comment: Actually, I think `cut` serves better but I've modified `awk` as well.

Comment: @anubhava `cut` works perfectly. Thanks so much for such a quick reply.

Comment: Great stuff, always nice to see traditional tools being used. @user261007 - note that despite your [tag:bash] tag, none of the attempts you made or solutions provided are bash-specific.

Comment: @ghoti Honestly it's probably because I don't understand what bash is.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
sed -e 's/_[^_\t]\+$//'
```

This is similar to your attempted solution, except that I replaced `.` with `[^_\t]` and I added a `$`. This guarantees that we will catch the last instance of `_`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @anubhava I fixed it.

Comment: @anubhava I fixed it again.

Comment: Didn't notice that it was giving me `ASSI-12_11 scaf0409557_70062.641` but `ASSI-13`. `sed 's/_[^_\t]+$//'` doesn't change anything at all :/

Comment: Oops, I had forgotten an \ before the `+`, I fixed it again. It now seems to work.

Comment: @redned Works now! Thanks!

Comment: The thing is OP asked for `I want to get rid of everything after the 3rd '_' character` which may or may not work with this. Read comment by @ghoti below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Let's try this one:

awk -F_ 'NF>2{sub(FS $NF,"")}1' file

ASSI-3_2    scaf0270669_20068.102
ASSI-4_3    scaf0189112_70083.538
ASSI-5_4    scaf0083789_70072.963
ASSI-8_7    scaf0423760_50193.589
ASSI-11_10  scaf0285971_60192.428
ASSI-12_11  scaf0409557_70062.641
ASSI-13_12  scaf0430981
```

Comment: Won't work since `_wgs` isn't always what comes after the underscore. I should have put other strings apart from `_wgs`, didn't think of that. I'll change it now.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\(.*_.*_.*\)_.*/\1/' file
```

Pattern match and remove everything from the third `_` onwards.